# How to find the first common number from a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary of lists. Each list contains many numbers. The lists can have different lengths. I am looking to find the **first common number in ALL lists**. **The answer has to be a function**.

For example in this case:

```
d = { 'case1' : [18, 17, 497, 298, 57, 82, 1], 'case2': [128, 184, 497,298,57, 1, 82], 'case3':[104,2828,3881, 497, 1, 38], 'case4': [392, 497, 573, 1]}
```

**The expected output is: 497**. I don't want to catch 1. I am only looking for 497.

All I have for now is this :

```
def find_first_common_number(dictionary_of_lists):
    for list_name in dictionary_of_lists:    #list name e.g. 'case1'
        for num1 in dictionary_of_lists[list_name]:
            #this is where I am going to have to find the first common 
            # number from all lists in the dictionary
            # the order this number appears in each list DOES NOT matter
```

I would appreciate your help on this. I looked through the list methods, couldn't do much as I am new to Python. If you could explain/comment your method would be great.

Comment: More suited for Code Review.

Comment: how do you determine what "first" is ... what if case2 had 298 before 497?

Comment: There could be a case where there would be more common numbers. But I am only looking for the first common number. So in list1 = [1,35, 2], list2 = [12,35,2] I am looking for number 35.

Comment: @HR123r there is not "first" though... what happens with this use case  list1 = [1,35, 2], list2 = [12,35,2], list3 = [1, 2, 35], list4 = [35,2,1], list5 = [2,1,35]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can i try this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

d = { 'case1' : [18, 17, 497, 298, 57, 82],
      'case2': [128, 184, 497,298,57,82],
      'case3':[104,2828,3881, 497, 38],
      'case4': [392, 497, 573]
      }

k = d.values()
# This sort will bring the shortest list in the front 
# will loop base on the shortest list.(optimization)
k.sort(key = lambda s: len(s))

def find_first_common_number(k):
    # lets loop base on the shortest list.
    # k[0] is the first list 
    for y in k[0]:
       if all([y in x for x in k[1:]]):
           return y
    return False
print find_first_common_number(k)
```

Output:
   497

Comment: I like this solution actually +1 ... i am curious how it would time test against my function (not curious enough to test...)

Comment: This one works too! I tried it with the lists including more common numbers and it only returns 497. Could you please explain what y, k[0], x and return false stand for, or the purpose they serve? Plus, I don't understand why you had to put k.sort(key = labda s: len(s)). Apart from optimisation, wouldn't code work without it? Thank you for helping me learn more Python.

Comment: @HR123r y is every number in your first list, k is all of the lists in your dictionary, so k[0] is the first list, x is every list in y, all() checks to see if its all of them... if there isn't a common number it returns false meaning there arent any common... theres also something called debugging... you should step through each thing and look at what its doing. best way to learn

Comment: @John Ruddell Thank you explaining me this. I will follow your advice. Thank you all for your input and next time I will try and make my questions clearer.

Comment: Thanks @JohnRuddell for explaning, i was away from keyboard :)

Answer (score 2):

```
def first_in_all(data):
    values = data.values()
    common_values = set(values[0]).intersection(*values[1:]) #this should create a set of all common values
    #im still not sure why order is important or how its determined for you
    #but if order is not important you might just return `common_values` here
    if not common_values:
       return None  #there were no common values
    for item in data[min(data.keys())]: 
        if item in common_values:
           return item #return first item that is found in the common_values set
```

Comment: Excellent. I tried it and it just returns just the first common number. 497 and doesn't return 1. Thank you!

Comment: Beasly Could you please explain a bit more the values[0] = set(values[0]), or link me to relevant Python docs? Thanks

Comment: it makes the first item a set so that the reduce line that follows will work... if you did not do that then it would complain that set.intersection expects a set

Comment: @JoranBeasley is that more efficient than this? `set(values[0]).intersection(*values[1:])` to return all of the common values in a set ?

Comment: @JohnRuddell I think that is a better solution .... editing now ... I didnt realize you could pass more than one list into the set.intersection :P (thanks these days its rare I learn something new about python :P)

Comment: haha cool I wasn't sure if reduce() was more efficient. I had put that in my answer :)

Comment: I also agree with "there is no first" and its an artificial construct but meh ...

Comment: one other thing about how this is computed.. the "first" element that is in all of the lists could be different depending on the list you choose to compare... aka the shortest could have 1, 2, 3 and then the longest could have 2, 1, 5, 6, 7... so if you are trying to find the first in the short list it may not be the first that appears in all lists :)

Answer (score 1):

one thing you can do is just do a set comparrison with the & operator

```
>>> d = { 'case1' : [18, 17, 497, 298, 57, 82], 'case2': [128, 184, 497,298,57,82], 'case3':[104,2828,3881, 497, 38], 'case4': [392, 497, 573]}
>>> a = set(d['case1']) & set(d['case2']) & set(d['case3']) & set(d['case4'])
>>> a
set([497])
```

[**DOCS**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects)

if you want it in a function you could just do it like this.

```
def find_common(d):
    all = list(d.values())
    common = set(all[0]).intersection(*all[1:])
    if not len(common):
        return None
    return common
```

However I firmly stand behind the notion that there is no "first" item. there can be so many use cases where there are overlapping "firsts" which makes no sense

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have two comments: This answer wouldn't be appropriate here, because if there was another common number e.g. case1=[282, 47, 39, 27] and case2 = [28,47,27] your answer returns set([47,27]). Secondly, this answer is not given as function. But thank you though.

Comment: @HR123r just like my comment on your answer `there is not "first" though... what happens with this use case list1 = [1,35, 2], list2 = [12,35,2], list3 = [1, 2, 35], list4 = [35,2,1], list5 = [2,1,35]` you can very easily put this into a function... simple copy paste

Comment: I really like your set intersection :P +1 and your assertion that there is no first is also correct imho

Comment: @JoranBeasley thanks! +1 to you too, if there was another requirement like sorting the numbers and finding the "first" lowest or greatest number would make sense... but not just based on the position in a list :P